# Is it possible to use an existing contracts storage as the seed data for a new contract that has the same storage schema?

Tags: smartpy, contract, storage, origination

Can you deploy a new copy of a contract with SmartPy and simultaneously copy the storage of an already existing contract that has an identical model into the freshly deployed contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible if you originate a contract from within a contract:

The example below duplicates the storage of `Creator` when originating `Created`. (**This will not work if the storage contains tickets, only duplicable types are allowed)**

```
import smartpy as sp

class Created(sp.Contract):
    def __init__(self):
        self.init(sp.big_map())

    @sp.entry_point
    def update(self):
        self.data[1] -= 1

class Creator(sp.Contract):
    def __init__(self):
        self.init(sp.big_map({1: 2}))

    @sp.entry_point
    def create(self):
        sp.create_contract(Created(), storage = self.data, amount = sp.amount)

    @sp.entry_point
    def update(self):
        self.data[1] += 1

sp.add_compilation_target("Creator", Creator())
```

Doing this off-chain is more complicated. You will need to query the contract storage with `/chains/main/blocks/head/context/contracts/<some_contract>/storage`, and if it contains any big_map, you will need to replace the `{ "int": <big_map_id> }` with the expanded map value by querying every big_map entry with `/chains/main/blocks/head/context/big_maps/<big_map_id>`. (**Gas and storage will be a limitation if the big_map has many entries**)

Comment: when you say doing it "off-chain" do you mean it is possible from a fresh origination and you just have to prepare the data beforehand, or do you mean that that it is only possible if the contract to be migrated deploys the new contract and there are just extra steps if there are bigmaps?

Comment: You need to prepare the data beforehand.

Comment: perfect, i was able to get this working but note the last part has `head/context/context/big_maps` in the url and it should just be `head/context/big_maps`

Comment: so you basically just create a custom version of `step_000_cont_0_storage.json` and pass that in as `--storage` flag on the `originate-contract` command in smartpy? and the old bigmaps will convert to new bigmap ids?

Comment: does the initial data limit form part of the existing 32kb limit?

Comment: Yes, those hard limits are defined for operations and blocks and can be accessed at: `/chains/main/blocks/head/context/constants`. field `max_operation_data_length`

Comment: About the previous question. You can not have a big_map pointer `{ "int": <big_map_id> } ` in the contract initial storage. You have to fetch all the entries and include it as map literal `{ Elt ...; }`